# cscript is not a valid Win32 application Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows

Trying to run cscript from commandline give the error 'cscript is not a valid Win32 application' on Windows Server 2003, with IIS 6 installed.

Comment: It needs to look to the 32-bit version of cscript. 

You gotta call `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe` with the full path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to look to the 32-bit version of cscript, rather than the 64 bit version, which is used in PATH.

Call `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe` with the full path.

Comment: I know on windows 64 bit %windir%\system32 is the native 64 bit and %windir%\sysWOW64 that is the 32 bit subsystem ...